# How to serialize subtypes with MsgPack in C#

Tags: c#, msgpack

i have a question regarding msgpack serialization in c#.
I have a base class and a class derived from base, each of them holding properties, for example:

```
class Base
{
    int PropertyA { get; set; }
}

class DerivedFromBase : Base
{
    int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally i have an object of a third class Container, for example:

```
class Container 
{
    Base ContainerProperty { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is, if ContainerProperty is of type DerivedFromBase, MsgPack serializes only PropertyA, not PropertyB! How can i achieve, that MsgPack internally recognize ContainerProperty to be a DerivedFromBase? Do i have to write a custom serializer or is there a "builtin" way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute `MessagePackRuntimeType` to have MsgPack analyze the type at runtime for serialization:

```
class Container 
{
    [MessagePackRuntimeType]
    Base ContainerProperty { get; set; }
}
```

For more details, see the [msgpack-cli
 documentation on polymorphism](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/wiki/Polymorphism)